# React: Absolute Paths from Root Folder using ViteJS with TypeScript

Tags: vite

So, in React, using vite, I'm trying to do the following structure, but seems I can't get it to work because I'm missing a concept or something, so the structure is as follows:

```
src/utils
src/routes
src/index.tsx
src/main.tsx
```

And on the `index.tsx`, I want to import utils and routes, and then call them at any root level as following: `import {Routes, Utils} from "@"`, but the way I did is not working.

Meanwhile, this is how I configured it with vite:

```js
resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `index.tsx` exports everything from `src/utils` and `src/routes`:

```js
// src/index.tsx
export * from './routes'
export * from './utils'
```

And configure TypeScript with a path alias for `@`:

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@": ["./src"], //  needed for barrel imports from '@'
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-react-barrel-imports?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.tsx,tsconfig.json)